# Quickest way to create a Shapely Polygon from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, shapely

I am trying to create a geometry column (Polygons) from a DataFrame that contains the following columns: xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax.

This is what my DataFrame (df) looks like:

```
        xmin           xmax          ymin          ymax
0 -715668.153951 -715418.153951  6.419357e+06  6.419607e+06
1 -715668.153951 -715418.153951  6.419357e+06  6.419607e+06
2 -715668.153951 -715418.153951  6.419357e+06  6.419607e+06
3 -715668.153951 -715418.153951  6.419357e+06  6.419607e+06
4 -715668.153951 -715418.153951  6.419357e+06  6.419607e+06
```

I've managed to do what I want with the following code:

```
def polygonise_2Dcells(df_row): 
    return Polygon([(df_row.xmin, df_row.ymin), (df_row.xmax, df_row.ymin),(df_row.xmax, df_row.ymax), (df_row.xmin, df_row.ymax)])
```

and then:

```
polys = df.apply(polygonise_2Dcells, axis=1)
```

While the above code works fine, 'apply' is rather slow for my needs (very big dataset). Thus, I am looking for a quicker way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Can your data fit in memory?

Comment: Probably yes, at least most of the times (I use it for different datasets)